# Removing attributes of an element on clicking outside with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

How can I remove an attribute of an element on click outside or on another `div` of same type? Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div data-something></div>
  <div data-something></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-something]");    

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {

  // Adding
  element.onclick = function() {
    this.setAttribute("data-adding", "");
  };

  // Removing -- Example
  element.onclickoutside = function() {
     this.removeAttribute("data-adding");
  };

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would probably use a click handler on the *document*, and then remove the attribute from any element that had it that wasn't in the bubbling path.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("*[data-adding][data-something]"), function(element) {
        var node, found = false;
        for (node = e.target; !found && node; node = node.parentNode) {
            if (node === element) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            element.removeAttribute("data-adding");
        }
    });
}, false);
```

...or something along those lines.

**Live Example:**

```js
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("*[data-adding]"), function(element) {
        var node, found = false;
        for (node = e.target; !found && node; node = node.parentNode) {
          if (node === element) {
            found = true;
          }
        }
        if (!found) {
          element.removeAttribute("data-adding");
        }
      });
    }, false);
```

```css
*[data-adding] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-adding data-something>One</div>
<div data-adding data-something>Two</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) inside a global click event handler to check if a click is outside an element, and handle the event appropriately:

```js
box = document.getElementById('box');
lastEvent = document.getElementById('event');

box.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // click inside box
  // (do stuff here...)
  lastEvent.textContent = 'Inside';
});

window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!box.contains(event.target)) {
    // click outside box
    // (do stuff here...)
    lastEvent.textContent = 'Outside';
  }
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffaaaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Click inside or outside me</div>

<div>Last event: <span id="event">(none)</span>
</div>
```